What type are the Dragons on these pages of Fizban's Treasury?
I am currently reading through Fizban's Treasury of Dragons a second time and I must admit I still struggle to identify the types of the Dragons depicted in a few of the artworks and would like to get your help in identifying the Dragons depicting on the following pages:

Page 14. This is probably the easiest. I suspect this to be a Gold Dragon, but its color scheme looks so dulled out, that I am not sure if this might be a Brass Dragon instead, as they both share a similar wing structure.
Page 158. This one is a bit trickier. The big one is obviously blue, as the artwork's caption states and the one flying on the top left is clearly a sapphire dragon. But what about the one on the right, that is the mount of that knight with the lance? It's clearly not a Gem Dragon, nor does it resemble any of the Chromatic Dragons, which leaves to believe it's a metallic dragon, but which one? The color looks most like a Bronze or Brass Dragon but not enough for me to know for sure. Or could it be a Copper Dragon that has changed its color to a greenish tone, like that metal does in real life?
Page 48. This is the one that is the biggest mystery to me and started this question in the first place. It has a light blue color scheme, but neither a Sapphire Dragon's gem skin, nor a Blue Dragon's horn and also doesn't really fit either of their hues of blue. Its features mostly resemble that of a Silver Dragon, but then why is it blue? Does this have anything to do with the Hidecarved Sigils described at that section, that this Dragon is meant to visualize?


Page 14: Definitely Gold Dragon
The art on page 14 is consistent with the Monster Manual description and art for a gold dragon:

A gold dragon has a sagacious face anointed with flexible spines that resemble whiskers. Its horns sweep back from its nose and brow, echoing twin frills that adorn its long neck. A gold dragon’s sail-like wings start at its shoulders and trace down to the tip of its tail, letting it fly with a distinctive rippling motion as if swimming through the air.


As for the other two, I’ve cross referenced their appearance with the MM descriptions and other art in Fizban’s and the MM, and none of them are a clear fit like the gold dragon is. It seems likely that the artists were directed to just make cool art rather than to make sure their dragon depictions fit 100% consistently with existing lore descriptions and prior art.


Page 158. what about the one on the right, that is the mount of that knight with the lance?

Dragonnel:
if you go to page 190 of the same book, you will see a strong resamble for  the images (IMVHO here are clear similarities in color, scales, claws, horns, end of the tail, size compared to their knight/Cavalier, and shape of the wings)
and their description is quite fitting too:

...distantly related to chromatic, gem and metallic dragons and resemble them  in basic... In some regions, dragonnels are raised from eggs to be used as aerial mounts.



Page 48. This is the one that is the biggest mystery to me...

despite the bluish color, this really seems to me the head of a Silver Dragon (see for example the image on this other answer taken from the monster manual of DnD 3.5)
So, IMVHO, the editor decided to change colors to provide more contrast with the gleaming runes (also because a Silver Dragon head with bright runes could have appeared as a grayscale image against the beige background).
Or maybe, this is a picture of the dragon at dawn, when the sky starts turning to dark blue and the silver scales reflect the incoming starred night...

I think both of your theories are correct. The only caveat I have is that the Dragon on page 158 looks alot like the Dragonnel in the Beastiary with one exception: its size. It does not look like a Large creature, it looks like a Huge one, and with that like an adult dragon. Or maybe that is just me? Regardless to accept an answer here I would need one that includes an explanation of all three Pages.

I agree that the dragon on page 48 is unquestionably a Silver Dragon. The facial features are very clear and don't resemble any other dragon to any great degree, the features being a good way to tell which dragon you're looking at regardless of color. Seems like it's just lit with a blue-ish light. Nice catch on the dragonnel, although I agree that the size seems off.

@coppereyecat re 158: I don't have my copy of Fizban's with me right now. Is there a human for scale or something?

@NoName  Yes. The dragon in question is being ridden by what is presumably a human, wearing armor, although I guess there is a small possibility it's actually a halfling or something and they're both closer to the viewer than assumed. The rider from hip to top of head is noticeably smaller than the dragon's visible neck and head, or the dragon's upper front le from shoulder to elbow. (The view is from behind so scale is a bit difficult)
